# heroku Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, maven, heroku, maven-3

i have been stuck for days no with no clue with this error

**heroku Logs**

```
2017-05-19T18:11:44.288620+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -Dserver.port=40569 -jar target/*.jar`
2017-05-19T18:11:46.509758+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2017-05-19T18:11:46.513097+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx350m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2017-05-19T18:11:46.599805+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class SpringBootWebApplication
2017-05-19T18:11:46.770670+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-05-19T18:11:46.753975+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-05-19T18:12:05.851023+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=cleverzone.herokuapp.com request_id=bfe2c1c5-2f6d-4062-910d-2b01a597406e fwd="197.49.77.195" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

when i tried and run bash on heroku server and run jar tf on the file

**here is the main class**
**it is really big too so i took those important and the maven**

```
guru/springframework/SpringBootWebApplication.class
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/guru.springframework/
META-INF/maven/guru.springframework/CleverZone/
META-INF/maven/guru.springframework/CleverZone/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/guru.springframework/CleverZone/pom.properties
```

**my Maven code**

```
it is really big so i put only the maven part

                <plugin>
                    <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>SpringBootWebApplication</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

now i have tried this in place of mainClass but no luck

```
guru.springframework.SpringBootWebApplication
```

**My Procfile**

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/*.jar
```

Comment: How do you run the application locally?

Comment: Also, why not use the SpringBoot Maven Plugin like this https://github.com/heroku/java-getting-started/blob/master/pom.xml#L90-L108

Comment: using sts ide i select the main class i think the problem is in my maven file ?

Comment: @codefinger i have tried that maven Plugin now it get me to older error "no main manifest attribute"